`recv` socket error EMSGSIZE when downloading file via HTTP/TCP/IPv6/LTE-M
I'm trying to download a largish file (~167KB) via HTTP/TCP/IPv6 over LTE on an nrf9160.The sockets' execution is offloaded to the modem.
The modem crashes every time around the same point during the download (~49KB). It's spits out error EMSGSIZE (122), Message too long.
The secure sockets on the modem have a buffer size limit 2KB. I made sure to set the sending chunk size to the minimum MTU for IPV6, 1280B.
I've tried to increase the size for just about every related Kconfig setting I can find with no change.
I am writing the recv() bytes directly to flash, but even when I don't do that and constantly overwrite the buffer the issue persists.
I realize this might be a device specific issue, but the Nordic forums haven't helped me out much and I can't for the life of figure out where the issue is.
Stack trace (The free()s & alloc()s are from NRF_MODEM_LIB_MEM_DIAG_ALLOC):
D: path: /firmware
D: accept: application/octet-stream
D: SEC_TAG: 1
D: Send Headers (size: 147):
GET /firmware HTTP/1.1
Host: [hostname]:443
User-Agent: EDB/0.3.0
Accept: application/octet-stream
Connection: close


I: shm alloc 0x20008534, size 20
I: shm free  0x20008534, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012854, size 36
I: lib alloc 0x2001287c, size 36
I: lib free  0x2001287c, size 36
I: lib free  0x20012854, size 36
I: Resolved [IPV6 address] (AF_INET6)
I: lib alloc 0x20012854, size 20
D: Connecting to [hostname]:443
I: shm alloc 0x20008534, size 20
I: shm free  0x20008534, size 20

D: addrinfo @0x200294f0: ai_family=2, ai_socktype=1, ai_protocol=6, sa_family=2, sin_port=bb01

I: shm alloc 0x20008534, size 148
I: shm free  0x20008534, size 148
I: Sent 147 bytes
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: Received Headers. Size: 592 bytes
I: Successful response code: 200

I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 776
D: Total: 0
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 776
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 2145
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 3514
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 4883
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 6252
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
D: recv bytes: 67
D: Total: 7621
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 7688
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 9057
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 10426
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1021
D: Total: 11795
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 12816
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 14185
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 15554
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1021
D: Total: 16923
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 17944
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 19313
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 20682
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 22051
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 23420
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 24789
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 26158
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
D: recv bytes: 665
D: Total: 27527
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 28192
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 29561
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 30930
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 32299
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 33668
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
D: recv bytes: 843
D: Total: 35037
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 35880
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 37249
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 38618
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 39987
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 41356
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 42725
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 44094
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
D: recv bytes: 665
D: Total: 45463
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 46128
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 47497
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 48866
I: lib alloc 0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib alloc 0x20012884, size 20
I: lib free  0x2001286c, size 20
I: lib free  0x20012884, size 20
D: recv bytes: 1369
D: Total: 50235
E: recv() body failed, Message too long, bytes: -1
E: EOF or error in response headers.
I: Closing socket 0
D: (main): close: ctx=0x2000d74c, fd=0
I: lib free  0x20012854, size 20

D: Response Headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 06 Jun 2024 15:52:16 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
[Cloudflare additional headers]

The problem function:
static int parse_response(
    int *sock, char *recv_body_buf, int recv_body_buf_size, _Bool write_nvs
) {
  int rc = 0;
  int state = 0;
  int bytes;
  long offset = 0;
  bool headers = true;
  int status;
  size_t headers_size = 0;

  do {
    if (headers) {
      bytes = recv(*sock, &headers_buf[offset], 1, 0);
      if (bytes < 0) {
        LOG_ERR("recv() headers failed, %s", strerror(errno));
        return bytes;
      }

      if ((state == 0 || state == 2) && headers_buf[offset] == '\r') {
        state++;
      } else if (state == 1 && headers_buf[offset] == '\n') {
        state++;
      } else if (state == 3) {
        headers_size = offset;
        LOG_INF("Received Headers. Size: %ld bytes", offset);

        headers = false;
        headers_buf[offset + 1] = '\0';
        offset = 0;

        status = parse_status();
        switch (status) {
          case HTTP_REDIRECT:
            return 1;
          case HTTP_CLIENT_ERROR:
            return -1;
          case HTTP_SERVER_ERROR:
            return -1;
          case HTTP_NULL:
            return -1;
          default:
            break;
        }
        continue;
      } else {
        state = 0;
      }
    } else {
      if (write_nvs) {
        bytes = recv(*sock, recv_body_buf, recv_body_buf_size, 0);
        if (bytes < 0) {
          LOG_ERR("recv() body failed, %s, bytes: %d", strerror(errno), bytes);
          return bytes;
        }
        LOG_DBG("recv bytes: %d", bytes);
        LOG_DBG("Total: %ld", offset);
        rc = write_buffer_to_flash(recv_body_buf, bytes, offset);
        if (rc < 0) {
          LOG_DBG("rc: %d, error: %s", rc, strerror(errno));
          return -1;
        }
      } else {
        bytes = recv(
            *sock, (recv_body_buf + offset), (recv_body_buf_size - offset), 0
        );
        if (bytes < 0) {
          LOG_ERR("recv() body failed, err %d\n", errno);
          return bytes;
        }
      }
    }
    offset += bytes;
  } while (bytes != 0); /* peer closed connection */

  LOG_INF("Received Body. Size: %ld bytes", offset);
  LOG_INF("Total bytes received: %ld", offset + headers_size);

  if (write_nvs) {
    return 0;
  }

  /* Make sure recv_buf is NULL terminated (for safe use with strstr) */
  if (offset < recv_body_buf_size) {
    *(recv_body_buf + offset) = '\0';
  } else {
    *(recv_body_buf + recv_body_buf_size - 1) = '\0';
  }

  return 0;
}

The rest of the file:
/** @def RECV_HEADER_BUF_SIZE
 *  @brief A macro that defines the max size for HTTP headers
 * buffer.
 */
#define HEADER_BUF_SIZE 1024

/** HTTP headers buffer with size defined by the
 * HEADER_BUF_SIZE macro. */
static char headers_buf[HEADER_BUF_SIZE] = "\0";

/* Setup TLS options on a given socket */
int tls_setup(int fd, char *hostname, sec_tag_t sec_tag) {
  int err;
  int verify;

  /* Security tag that we have provisioned the certificate with */
  sec_tag_t tls_sec_tag[] = {sec_tag};

  /* Set up TLS peer verification */
  enum {
    NONE = 0,
    OPTIONAL = 1,
    REQUIRED = 2,
  };

  verify = REQUIRED;

  err = setsockopt(fd, SOL_TLS, TLS_PEER_VERIFY, &verify, sizeof(verify));
  if (err) {
    LOG_ERR("Failed to setup peer verification, %s", strerror(errno));
    return err;
  }

  err = setsockopt(
      fd, SOL_TLS, TLS_SEC_TAG_LIST, tls_sec_tag, sizeof(tls_sec_tag)
  );
  if (err) {
    LOG_ERR("Failed to setup TLS sec tag, %s", strerror(errno));
    return err;
  }

  err = setsockopt(fd, SOL_TLS, TLS_HOSTNAME, hostname, strlen(hostname));
  if (err) {
    LOG_ERR("Failed to setup TLS hostname, %s", strerror(errno));
    return err;
  }

  return 0;
}

static int parse_status(void) {
  char *ptr;
  int code;

  ptr = strstr(headers_buf, "HTTP");
  if (ptr == NULL) {
    LOG_ERR("Missing HTTP status line");
    return HTTP_NULL;
  }

  ptr = strstr(headers_buf, " ");
  if (ptr == NULL) {
    LOG_ERR("Improperly formatted HTTP status line");
    return HTTP_NULL;
  }

  code = atoi(ptr);

  switch (code) {
    case 100 ... 199:
      LOG_INF("Informational response code: %d", code);
      return HTTP_INFO;
    case 200 ... 299:
      LOG_INF("Successful response code: %d", code);
      return HTTP_SUCCESS;
    case 300 ... 399:
      LOG_INF("Redirection response code: %d", code);
      return HTTP_REDIRECT;
    case 400 ... 499:
      LOG_INF("Client error response code: %d", code);
      return HTTP_CLIENT_ERROR;
    case 500 ... 599:
      LOG_INF("Server error response code: %d", code);
      return HTTP_SERVER_ERROR;
    default:
      LOG_ERR("HTTP status code missing or incorrect. Response code: %d", code);
      return HTTP_NULL;
  }
}

static char *get_redirect_location(void) {
  char *ptr;

  ptr = strstr(headers_buf, "Location:");
  if (ptr == NULL) {
    ptr = strstr(headers_buf, "location:");
    if (ptr == NULL) {
      LOG_ERR("Location header missing");
      return NULL;
    }
  }

  ptr += 9;

  while (*ptr == ' ') {
    ptr++;
  }

  *strstr(ptr, "\r\n") = '\0';

  return ptr;
}

static int send_http_request(
    char *hostname, char *path, char *accept, sec_tag_t sec_tag,
    char *recv_body_buf, int recv_body_buf_size, _Bool write_nvs
) {
  int bytes;
  int err;
  int headers_size;
  size_t offset;
  char *ptr;
  int redirect;
  int sock = -1;

  struct addrinfo *addr_inf;
  static struct addrinfo hints = {
      .ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM, .ai_flags = AI_NUMERICSERV
  };

  LOG_DBG("hostname: %s", hostname);
  LOG_DBG("path: %s", path);
  LOG_DBG("accept: %s", accept);
  LOG_DBG("SEC_TAG: %d", sec_tag);

retry:
  redirect = 0;

  ptr = stpcpy(&headers_buf[0], "GET ");
  ptr = stpcpy(ptr, path);
  ptr = stpcpy(ptr, " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
  ptr = stpcpy(ptr, "Host: ");
  ptr = stpcpy(ptr, hostname);
  if (sec_tag == NO_SEC_TAG) {
    ptr = stpcpy(ptr, ":80\r\n");
  } else {
    ptr = stpcpy(ptr, ":443\r\n");
  }
  // TODO: Change APP_VERSION_STRING to APP_VERSION_TWEAK_STRING when possible
  ptr = stpcpy(
      ptr,
      "User-Agent: EDB/" APP_VERSION_STRING " Stop-ID/" CONFIG_STOP_ID "\r\n"
  );
  ptr = stpcpy(ptr, "Accept: ");
  ptr = stpcpy(ptr, accept);
  ptr = stpcpy(ptr, "\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n");

  headers_size = (ptr - &headers_buf[0]);

  LOG_DBG("Send Headers (size: %d):\n%s", headers_size, &headers_buf[0]);

  if (sec_tag == NO_SEC_TAG) {
    err = getaddrinfo(hostname, "80", &hints, &addr_inf);
  } else {
    err = getaddrinfo(hostname, "443", &hints, &addr_inf);
  }
  if (err) {
    LOG_ERR("getaddrinfo() failed, %s", strerror(errno));
    return errno;
  }

  char peer_addr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

  if (inet_ntop(
          addr_inf->ai_family,
          &((struct sockaddr_in *)(addr_inf->ai_addr))->sin_addr, peer_addr,
          INET6_ADDRSTRLEN
      ) == NULL) {
    LOG_ERR("inet_ntop() failed, %s", strerror(errno));
    return errno;
  }

  LOG_INF("Resolved %s (%s)", peer_addr, net_family2str(addr_inf->ai_family));

  if (sec_tag == NO_SEC_TAG) {
    sock = socket(addr_inf->ai_family, SOCK_STREAM, addr_inf->ai_protocol);
  } else if (IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_MBEDTLS)) {
    sock = socket(
        addr_inf->ai_family, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NATIVE_TLS, IPPROTO_TLS_1_2
    );
  } else {
    sock = socket(addr_inf->ai_family, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TLS_1_2);
  }

  if (sock == -1) {
    LOG_ERR("Failed to open socket!\n");
    goto clean_up;
  }

  if (sec_tag != NO_SEC_TAG) {
    err = tls_setup(sock, hostname, sec_tag);
    if (err) {
      goto clean_up;
    }
  }

  LOG_DBG(
      "Connecting to %s:%d", hostname,
      ntohs(((struct sockaddr_in *)(addr_inf->ai_addr))->sin_port)
  );
  err = connect(sock, addr_inf->ai_addr, addr_inf->ai_addrlen);
  if (err) {
    LOG_ERR("connect() failed, %s", strerror(errno));
    goto clean_up;
  }

  LOG_DBG(
      "addrinfo @%p: ai_family=%d, ai_socktype=%d, ai_protocol=%d, "
      "sa_family=%d, sin_port=%x\n",
      addr_inf, addr_inf->ai_family, addr_inf->ai_socktype,
      addr_inf->ai_protocol, addr_inf->ai_addr->sa_family,
      ((struct sockaddr_in *)addr_inf->ai_addr)->sin_port
  );

  offset = 0;
  do {
    bytes = send(sock, &headers_buf[offset], headers_size - offset, 0);
    if (bytes < 0) {
      LOG_ERR("send() failed, %s", strerror(errno));
      goto clean_up;
    }
    offset += bytes;
  } while (offset < headers_size);

  LOG_INF("Sent %d bytes", offset);

  redirect =
      parse_response(&sock, recv_body_buf, recv_body_buf_size, write_nvs);
  if (redirect < 0) {
    LOG_ERR("EOF or error in response headers.");
  }

clean_up:
  LOG_INF("Closing socket %d", sock);
  err = close(sock);
  if (err) {
    LOG_ERR("close() failed, %s", strerror(errno));
  }

  (void)freeaddrinfo(addr_inf);

  LOG_DBG("Response Headers:\n%s", &headers_buf[0]);

  if (redirect == 1) {
    goto redirect;
  }

  return 0;

redirect:
  ptr = get_redirect_location();
  char redirect_hostname_buf[255];
  LOG_INF("Redirect location: %s", ptr);

  /* Assume the host is the same */
  if (*ptr == '/') {
    path = strcpy(redirect_hostname_buf, ptr);
    LOG_DBG("path ptr: %s", path);
    /* Assume we're dealing with a url */
  } else if (*ptr == 'h') {
    if (strncmp(ptr, "https", 5) == 0) {
      if (sec_tag == NO_SEC_TAG) {
        LOG_ERR(
            "Redirect requires TLS, but a TLS sec_tag was assigned. Assign "
            "correct sec_tag in the code "
            "Aborting."
        );
        return 1;
      }
      ptr += 8;
    } else {
      ptr += 7;
      sec_tag = NO_SEC_TAG;
    }
    hostname = ptr;
    ptr = strstr(ptr, "/");
    *ptr++ = '\0';

    path = stpcpy(redirect_hostname_buf, hostname);
    *++path = '/';

    (void)strcpy((path + 1), ptr);
    hostname = redirect_hostname_buf;
  } else {
    LOG_ERR("Bad redirect location");
    return 1;
  }

  goto retry;
}

int http_get_firmware(char *write_buf, int write_buf_size) {
  int err;

  if (k_sem_take(&lte_connected_sem, K_SECONDS(30)) != 0) {
    LOG_ERR("Failed to take lte_connected_sem");
    err = 1;
  } else {
    err = send_http_request(
        CONFIG_OTA_HOSTNAME, CONFIG_OTA_PATH, "application/octet-stream",
        JES_SEC_TAG, write_buf, write_buf_size, true
    );

    k_sem_give(&lte_connected_sem);
  }

  return err;
}

Outside the file:
void download_update(void) {
  char write_buf[1500];

  if (!device_is_ready(external_flash)) {
    LOG_WRN("external_flash isn't ready!");
  }

  write_block_size = flash_get_write_block_size(external_flash);
  LOG_DBG("write_block_size %d", write_block_size);
  (void)http_get_firmware(write_buf, sizeof(write_buf));
}

int write_buffer_to_flash(char *data, size_t len, long offset) {
  if (flash_write(external_flash, offset, data, len)) {
    LOG_ERR("flash_write failed, %s", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}


For now I got things working by fragmenting and retrying until the download is complete.
I have to close the socket and create a new one to stop the issue from happening again immediately.
